# How to use logical conjunction properly

Tags: logic, operator-theory, predicate-logic

On [this website](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Cylinder.html) in equation (20) they use

$$
d \, S = a \, d \, u \land d \, v
$$

I have learned that $\land$ is the truth-functional operator of logical conjunction and that such logical operators are used between expressions evaluating either true or false.

In the equation/expression(?) above, can the two operands(?) $d \, S = a \, d \, u$ and $d \, v$ separately evaluate to a truth value? Otherwise, I haven't understood how to use $\land$ properly.

Comment: It is notation for **wedge product**, no connection with logical and.

Comment: You sir made my day :) But André is right.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [wedge product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exterior_algebra) as used in e.g. $\mathrm du \wedge \mathrm dv$ is completely separate from [logical conjunction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_conjunction) $\alpha\land\beta$.

There are even two TeX commands: `\wedge` and `\land`, where the latter is to be used for conjunction ("logical and"), to keep the two separated in writing your documents.